# How to limit and skip after grouping in a GraphQL query to paginate the tags list page?

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to paginate the blog tags list page in a Gatsby site, the tags are defined in the frontmatter of the MDX files:

```
---
title: Blog Post Title
date: 2020-05-20
tags: ["Markdown", "Gatsby", "JavaScript"]
---
```

Paginating the posts is easy using `limit` and `skip` passed in the page `context` object:

```
query Posts($limit: Int!, $skip: Int!) {
  allMdx(
    sort: { fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC }
    limit: $limit
    skip: $skip
  ) {
    nodes {
      ...
  }
}
```

But this doesn't apply for paginating the tags list page, this is going to `limit` and `skip` on `allMdx`, so we're going to get the same tag on multiple pages and also the `totalCount` is not going to be the total posts for a tags but the total for the `limit`ed posts.

```
query Tags($limit: Int!, $skip: Int!) {
  allMdx(limit: $limit, skip: $skip) {
    group(field: frontmatter___tags) {
      fieldValue
      totalCount
    }
  }
}
```

So how can I apply `limit` and `skip` on the `group` and not on the posts? What I can do is get all the tags for each page and use `limit` and `skip` in the component to show only the current page's tags, but I don't think this is the best way to do it.

Comment: read about "gatsby create node" ... during page cration (loop) you can collect tags (create node) ... then create tags pages

Comment: @xadm Thank you, I've followed your suggestion, and now I'm passing the tags of each page in the `context`, I used to only pass the page number and total items only, but still I would like to know how to do the same using the GraphQL query.

Comment: .... create [tag] nodes ... tags for every page should be available by frontmatter, no need to pass it separately

Comment: @xadm are you talking about the post tags? I'm talking about a `/tags` page that lists all the tags and the number of posts for each tag, this is the page that I want to paginate.

Answer (score 4):

During iteration over pages (where create page is used) you can create tag nodes.

- create an empty `tags` object (before iteration, for by name addressing),
- in loop (for every page):

  - loop over page tags (from frontmater `tags`):

    - create `tags[tag_name]` object (if not exists) with `posts` array property;
    - insert current page `slug` into `tags[tag_name].posts`

At the end (after create page loop) you have data collected in the structure like:

```
tags={
  "tag_1" : {
    posts [
      "slug_1",
      "slug_2"
    ]
  },
  "tag_2" : {
    posts [
      "slug_2",
      "slug_3",
      "slug_4"
    ]
  }
}
```

By iteration over this object you can create tag nodes with {tag_name, posts, post_count}.

After this you can create `/tags` pages. You can query for nodes collection.

You should be able (test in playground) to paginate them for tags index pages, you can display tag name, amount of pages and even pages links (expand amount component view? `posts` and `post_count` passed as props).